# Split Or explode value and remove characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a longtext field in table that return long string value as bellow:

I want to split the dates value using sql query:

```
response value = "a:4:{i:0;s:10:\"2019-11-15\";i:1;s:10:\"2021-11-16\";i:2;s:10:\"2022-11-02\";i:3;s:10:\"2022-11-02\";}"
```

Should be like this:

2019-11-15, 2021-11-16, 2022-11-02, .....

```
SELECT REPLACE(dates_value, 'a:4:{i:0;s:10:','/','\') FROM table ;
```

Thanks

Comment: fyi, that's serialized data. You can use [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) in PHP to access it. Is `php` even relevant for this question?

Comment: This value is a serialized array, which you should _never_ modify manually (you shouldn't store it either, but that's on a different page..). Secondly, if your SQL query has difficulties with quotes, your have obviously not used prepared statements - once you do that, the problem will vanish...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unserialize` to put the response into an array.

```
$response_value = "a:4:{i:0;s:10:\"2019-11-15\";i:1;s:10:\"2021-11-16\";i:2;s:10:\"2022-11-02\";i:3;s:10:\"2022-11-02\";}";
$array = unserialize($response_value);
```

The Array:

```
array (
  0 => "2019-11-15",
  1 => "2021-11-16",
  2 => "2022-11-02",
  3 => "2022-11-02",
)
```

With `implode` you get the date values as a string.

```
$string = implode(',',$array);
// string(43) "2019-11-15,2021-11-16,2022-11-02,2022-11-02"
```